# Numpy - reshape and flatten array

Tags: numpy

How do I reshape this array `y`:

```
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...,
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

Into:

```
array([0,
       0,
       0,
       ...,
       1,
       0,
       0])
```

using `numpy`?

Note:

I have obtained y from

```
y = df[['Goal']].values
```

and `df[['Goal']]` is:

```
    Goal
6234    0
6261    0
6328    0
6444    0
6452    0
... ...
424002  0
424087  0
424088  1
424142  0
424148  0
```

I don't get why scalars are being put into lists..

Comment: Look at `y.shape`.  Arrays have a `ravel` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df[['Goal']]` returns a dataframe because you passed a list of column names to `df` (in comparison `df['Goal']` returns a single column). A dataframe is by default 2D array, which is why `.values` returns a 2D array. To get a 1d array, you can either access `.values` through single column, which is 1D in nature, i.e. `df.Goal.values`

```
df.Goal.values
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Or you can flatten the 2D array by reshaping it `df[['Goal']].values.reshape(-1)`:

```
df[['Goal']].values.reshape(-1)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: just for completeness, can also `.flatten()` and `.ravel()` (and probably more)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reshape(-1)` as following :

```
import numpy as np
dummy_arr = np.array([[0],[0],[0],[1],[0],[0]])
arr = dummy_arr.reshape(-1)
```

it will give you output as:

```
Out[1]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```